# What could this plant be?

Tags: identification

I am from Mumbai - west coast of India, tropical weather.

In a pot that I had bought from a local nursery with an ivy plant, a new plant has grown.

It has violet colored tiny flowers - one to two cm. The flowers attract a lot of insects and I can also several green colored pods about 4cm in length.

What plant could it be?

Please see attached image. It shows a flower and an insect attracted to it:

[image]